# ggplot - Find coordinates of facet spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I have, e.g., the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rexp(100), grp = factor(sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~grp) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

and want to add a vertical line between the two plots - that is, in the middle of the panel spacing. My problem is, I am not sure of how to get the coordinates of the inner plot edges / the panel spacing in native units.

Both panels have unit 0.5 npc -- and I am not sure how I would convert this. I tried using viewports, but that did not work. Is there a way other than arranging plot 1 - plot of vertical line - plot 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind? You can tweak around with the parameter to change the position where the line will appear.

```r
# loading the libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)

# preparing the data
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 y = rexp(100),
                 grp = factor(sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)))

# preparing the plot
plot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ grp) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))

# preparing the line
gline <- grid::linesGrob(x = 0.5)

# plotting both the plot and the line
cowplot::ggdraw() +
  cowplot::draw_plot(plot) +
  cowplot::draw_plot(gline)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-01-24 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: Yes, basically. However, I would prefer to find the precise coordinates so it can be in the exact midpoint :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(grid)
library(gtable)
library(magrittr)

ggplotGrob(p) %>%
  gtable_add_grob(segmentsGrob(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), 
                  t = 4, b = 8, l = 7, r = 7)  %>%
  grid.draw()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5m8g.png)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: Well, theoretically yes, but 1) I would like to add the vertical line in the exact middle of the two facets and 2) how did you acquire those coordinates?